# Facebook Like Button Does not Show Up On a popup box that is using a delay (on firefox and IE)

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup, facebook-like, delay

I have this problem with a popup plugin.

the popup has a 5 second delay. (popup appears after 5 seconds)

whenever the delay is set, the facebook like button does not appear on firefox & internet explorer. it only appears in google chrome.

you can see the popup in action on http://palimashop.com

here's the javascript http://palimashop.com/wp-content/plugins/social-traffic-pop/stp.js?ver=1.0

The fb like button is working fine when delay is not being used.

How can I get the facebook like button to show up on firefox when delay is enabled?

I will appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: The links to the JavaScript is dead.